# Updating row by row

Tags: php, mysqli

Upon clicking on the button edit, i'm trying to update/insert my database (col:note). However if i change the value in one row, the same value is updated for all rows. I tried adding a WHERE condition (based on afnumber<-- unique id) for the insert and update sql, but couldn't get it to work. Any help please?

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jr', 'root', 'Js');
    $conn->exec("set names utf8");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $num_rows = $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees')->fetchColumn(); 
    $pages = new Paginator($num_rows,9,array(15,3,6,9,12,25,50,100,250,'All'));
    echo $pages->display_pages();
    echo "<span class=\"\">".$pages->display_jump_menu().$pages->display_items_per_page()."</span>";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT employees.afnumber,employees.name,employees.dateofemployment,employees.actualpost,employees.department FROM employees WHERE employees.status='Employed' AND (employees.afnumber LIKE '%$search%' OR employees.name LIKE '%$search%') ORDER BY employees.afnumber DESC LIMIT :start,:end");
    $stmt->bindParam(':start', $pages->limit_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end', $pages->limit_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $ewhtable = "<table class='sortable'><tr><th>AFNumber</th><th>Employee Name</th><th>Years of Service</th><th>Actual Post</th><th>Department</th><th>Note</th><th>Deducted Hours</th></tr>\n";
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $years=explode("/", $row[2]);
        $years[2]=intval(date ('Y')) - $years[2];

$sql="SELECT note,deductedwh FROM editedworkhours WHERE afnumber='$row[0]'";

$var = "";
$varr = "";  

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result2 = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($result2 AS $row2) {
  $var .= $row2['deductedwh'] . "\n";
    $varr .= $row2['note'] . "\n";
}
        $Id = $row[0];
        $ewhtable .= "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$years[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td><td>$row[4]</td><td><form method='post'><input type='text' name='Note' value='$varr' style=' padding: 10px;border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:200px; height:2px;'><input type='submit' id='search' name='edit' alt='search' value=''></form></td><td>$var</td></tr>\n";
    }



    $ewhtable .= "</table>\n";
    echo $ewhtable;

    exportTable(str_replace("&","",$ewhtable),"EmployeeDeductedWorkHoursTable");
    echo $pages->display_pages();
    echo "<p class=\"paginate\">Page: $pages->current_page of $pages->num_pages</p>\n";

          if(isset($_POST['edit']))
    {   
        $note = $_POST['Note'];  

     $sql1="SELECT Note FROM editedworkhours"; 

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
  {

  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  }
    if($rowcount==0)
     {
 $sql="INSERT INTO editedworkhours (Note) VALUES ('$note')";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     }
     else
     {
 $sql2 = "UPDATE editedworkhours SET Note= '$note'";
 $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
     }

    }
    echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Where is your attempt with the `WHERE`?

Comment: @Epodax to update or insert note, where the column afnumber = the afnumber of the row where note was edited or inserted

Comment: See YourCommonSense's answer, also, I still don't see a WHERE condition in your UPDATE query.

Comment: @Epodax it's not in the code, i removed it

Comment: Why would you remove it? We can't help you without the code that isn't working, using WHERE is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Epodax i know but i'm not sure what value to give to afnumber.. 
$sql="INSERT INTO editedworkhours (Note) VALUES ('$note') WHERE afnumber=' ' ";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87758/discussion-between-dan-and-epodax).

Comment: I'd recommend you find a tutorial on how to do Inserts / Updates with mysql, it isn't that advanced.

Comment: @Epodax $sql="INSERT INTO editedworkhours (Note) VALUES ('$note') WHERE afnumber='$row[0]' ";

Comment: That's what i'm doing, but it's always going to update the first value only wherever i update.

Comment: I'm not going to work through your code to fix it, BUT, don't use WHERE in  a INSERT query, use it at the UPDATE query. Again, find a tutorial on how to do mysql operations with php.

Comment: @Epodax ok thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are too many errors in this code, starting from lack of error reporting, direct danger of SQL injection, mixing different DB APIs, lack of proper SQL and so on - too much to make it answerable in one post.

This question have to be closed as too broad and you have to sit with your textbooks for couple more hours.